# start parse-server with launchd on mac os

Tags: parse-server, launchd, macos-high-sierra

I have parse-server installed on high sierra, that i run with "npm start -- config/config.json" on a shell.
as my mac reboots from time to time, i'd like to make it start when mac os reboots.
i have mongodb running this way with a plist (provided by the install).
Anyone could lead me to do the same with parse-server and parse-dashboard using launchd and lauchctl (I am not used to use this technic and i can't find anything by googling it)

thanks a lot for any help you can provide.

Edit:
I have the path set with /usr/local/bin, where I have a alias to parse-server.
If i run 'parse-server path/to/configrep/config.json' in the shell, works fine.
i created the following plist:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
   <plist version="1.0">
   <dict>
     <key>Label</key>
     <string>com.parse-server</string>
     <key>Program</key>
     <string>/usr/local/bin/parse-server</string>
     <key>RunAtLoad</key>
     <true/>
     <key>StandardOutPath</key>
     <string>/usr/local/var/log/parse-server/console.log</string>
     <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
     <string>/usr/local/var/log/parse-server/error.log</string>
   </dict>
   </plist>
```

going to read the error.log file, I got:

```
env: node: No such file or directory,
```

where I should have an error for the missing config file.

Anyone has got an idea?